# How do I get the size of a Cassandra table using the Python driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-python-driver

To archive this using Cassendra Shell :

```
nodetool cfstats -- <keyspace>.<tablename>
```

Python Package - [cassendra-driver](https://pypi.org/project/cassandra-driver/)

Docs - [cassendra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/api/cassandra/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you're running on Cassandra 4.0+, you can use Virtual Tables to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM system_views.disk_usage
WHERE keyspace_name='stackoverflow' AND table_name='baseball_stats';


 keyspace_name | table_name     | mebibytes
---------------+----------------+-----------
 stackoverflow | baseball_stats |         1

(1 rows)
```

I wrote an article on Virtual Tables early last month, if you'd like more information:

[Leveraging Virtual Tables in Apache Cassandra 4.0](https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/leveraging-virtual-tables-in-apache-cassandra-4-0-520059bb96b7)

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise it was recorded in the virtual tables. Since they're local to a node, do you aggregate the values from all nodes?

Comment: @ErickRamirez yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

The metrics in `nodetool tablestats` (formerly `cfstats`) is not exposed to the drivers so you cannot get this information via CQL.

These metrics are only exposed via JMX. Cheers!

Comment: Is there any feasible way to get size something like exporting into JSON and find size ?